# Distance between two parametric curves

Tags: derivatives, curves

Given the trajectories of two objects
$$r(t)=(4\cos(t),2\sin(t))$$
$$s(t)=(2\sin(2t),3\cos(2t))$$
I have to evaluate
$$\left.\frac{dD}{dt}\right|_{t=\pi}$$
where $D$ is the distance between them. May I say
$$D(t)=r(t)-s(t)?$$
Or should it be
$$D(t)=\sqrt{r^2(t)-s^2(t)}?$$

Comment: You mean _euclidean_ distance ? that would be $\sqrt{\left(r(t)-s(t)\right)^2}$

Comment: @MBobrik why $(r-s)^2$ and not $r^2-s^2$?

Comment: because that's how it's _defined_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: so it's just $|r-s|$?

Comment: yes, that's euclidean distance

Comment: just to avoid misunderstanding, r and s are 2D vectors, so $|r-s|$ is the norm of the $r-s$ vector, not just absolute value ;-)